# background-color animation using div:hover only effects text. how to change the entire div background-color?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with two text links inside, and I want to change the background and border color of said div.

The solution I came up with only changes the background color of the text, and not the div.
[Photo of background color changing only behind text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aP1X.png)

For reference, here's what I was expecting: [Mockup of what I was expecting, the entire background is lighter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtI42.png)

Here's my incredibly messy code (div:hover is on line 17), and thank you so much in advance if you actually figure out how to fix this. I'm genuinely stumped.

```
    <div class="mainbox">
      <div class="text">
        <div class="one"><a href="https://google.com/">Link 1</a></div>
        <br> <br> <br>
        <div class="two"><a href="https://google.com/">Link 2</a></div>
    </div>
```

```
.mainbox {  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 1.25em; 
  background: #232A33; 
  border: solid 1px #88ABEB; 
  padding: 30px 30px; 
  height: 25%;
  width: 40%;

  /* hover animation */
  div:hover {background: #2B333D; transition: 0.2s;}
  
}
```

*alternatively: a codepen link: https://codepen.io/platored/pen/MWLOJWz*

I tried changing the background color, and it changed the background color behind the text, rather than in the whole div.
I assumed it would change it for the full div, because I specified the background color earlier in the block.

Comment: If you want to change `.mainbox`'s styles on hover, why are you doing `.mainbox div:hover` instead of `.mainbox:hover`?